# Replace Nan with previous row value in pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a dataframe named `purchase_df` with columns (`purchase_item`, `purchase_date`, `purchase_quantity`, `purchase_price_unit`, `sales_quantity`) and some of the value of `purchase_price_unit` is **Nan**(empty) and I need to replace **Nan** value with previous month value

Note:- I saw this one ([Python pandas, replace a NAN on a column with previous value on the same column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71531930/python-pandas-replace-a-nan-on-a-column-with-previous-value-on-the-same-column)) but here they haven't used group by which is major problem in this task.

For this I tried doing this

```
# grouped = purchase_df.groupby('purchase_item')
grouped = purchase_df.groupby(['purchase_item','purchase_date'])
purchase_df['purchase_price_unit'] = grouped['purchase_price_unit'].apply(lambda x: x.ffill())
```

Here I group the data by `purchase_item` and `purchase_date` and used `ffill()` which fill value of previous rows but it didn't work even though this method replace **nan** with previous rows if I group by just using `purchase_item` but here I need to group by according to `purchase_item` as well as `purchase_date`. Help me out

Comment: Please add a few rows from your dataset as a reproducible input and an expected output. This will help others to answer your question better. Please read how to add a [mre]

Answer (score 0):

Apply the function within your groupby objects:

```
purchase_df.groupby(['purchase_item','purchase_date']).apply(lambda x: x.ffill())
```

Comment: i got same thing as above